# RPM jumps up & back down at 40mph

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, dodge, rpm

My question is for a 2006 Dodge Magnum, 2.7 liter engine.

Just over the past month or so, I noticed when I'm cruisung, just coming from a dead stop,  when I'm at 40 mph my car kinda feels like it jumps and the RPM jumps to over the three grand and back down to where it usually is, somewhere around two thousand. This was more sporadic, but now it's doing at almost every time...

**What could possibly be wrong with it?**

I don't have much money, but I need to get to work and home.

It may be me, but it seems like my car doesn't have enough get up and go when I put it in reverse from a flat straight away.

I don't think I'm driving my car any different now then I was before :-/

Any help with these question would be totally appreciated.

Comment: How kms have it been running from last clutch plate running?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that your clutch is slipping. Either because the mechanism isn't working properly (rare but possible) or the clutch is worn (very likely).

Comment: He did put in the tags it is an automatic transmission (though he put the word "standard" before the engine type, which I removed. I don't think it's a clutch problem in the normal sense.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your transmission oil level? Low oil level could cause your symptoms. Whilst checking your oil level is there any water contamination? Coolant can get into trans fluid from the trans-oil cooler. You need to let your vehicle repairer carry out an examination of its transmission.

Comment: No but from what im hearing I maybe should do that. Today it didnt do it as much, but it still did do it.  Ill let you know what happens- if it was low or ok..

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a common symptom of a dirty or contaminated oil filter! I am speaking of an "automatic transmission fluid" filter. it is similar to a motor oil filter except it filters "ATF"instead of Petroleum oil! When the filter is dirty or contaminated it Beaks down to a Thinner less effective consistency. At that point it can't develop enough pressure to operate the valves and pressure sensitive devices in any automatic transmission. That's when you get symptoms of slippage and or Engine racing with no increase of road speed. That can also feel like a power loss. It needs to be check by an automatic transmission shop or qualified Mechanic.

The condition can and will over time cause harm or damage to your Transmission. The longer you wait the more costly! The good side is Most Automatic transmission shops will do a standard service on your trans' and inspect and change the filter as part of the servicing! During that process they will find out if you need any more than JUST a Service.

Servicing your transmission will be mentioned in your operators/Owners Manual. It will tell you how often or time interval to do a standard scheduled trans'service! Please service earlier rather than later than indicated interval. It is the cheapest kind of insurance to be early(or before damage),rather than "just a little later" than suggested and pay for repairs instead of service.

Good luck and hoping you have only a service needed! Pat (CookieMonster)

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a problem with the Fast Idle Air Control.
Maybe this video will help you just to give you the basic idea of the Idle Air Control.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L788jKEVblY